# How to implement automatically adding metatags

Tags: symfony, twig, meta-tags

I have symfony project where I need metatags to be changed depending on pagination number. For example for page articles/1 i need metatags to be

```
Title: Articles - page 1 Description Articles - page 1
```

and so on. Project uses Twig

Comment: Read the examples here https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#template-inheritance-and-layouts

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by passing metadata from child twig template to parent within block. I dont know if this is a good or bad solution, but its working